# How to silence `Shell` (ruby stdlib) `notify` feature?

Tags: ruby

```ruby
require 'shell'
sh = Shell.new
sh.verbose = false
sh.debug = false
print sh.system('date')
```

### Expected output

```
Wed Nov 10 13:08:09 EST 2021
```

### Observed output

```
shell(#<Th:0x00007fd016064058 run>): /bin/date
Wed Nov 10 13:08:09 EST 2021
```

The unwanted line comes from `Shell::CommandProcessor#notify`

Comment: `Shell` was [removed from stdlib in Ruby 2.7](https://rubyreferences.github.io/rubychanges/2.7.html#libraries-excluded-from-the-standard-library) and must be installed as a regular gem named [shell](https://github.com/ruby/shell)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some investigation there seems to be a confusing design flaw (or feature?) in `Shell`. Initally it seems you should be able to mutate `verbose` and `debug` on an *instance* of `Shell`, but it turns out the root `notify` method itself lives in the *class*, not the instance.

Hence instance level settings will only have limited effect, as the class method `Shell.notify` will be unaware of instance settings.

**Solution - use class-level settings instead:**

```
Shell.verbose = false
Shell.debug   = false
```

Output will now be only:

```
Wed Nov 10 13:08:09 EST 2021
```